# Adding Braintree plugin breaks social login on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login, google-signin, braintree

I am facing a really strange problem and would appreciate any help - currently I have an app that has social login using **flutter_facebook_login (3.0.0)** for Facebook and **google_sign_in (4.1.1)** for Google.

They are working fine, but when I add one specific plugin - *flutter_braintree* (or *braintree_payment*), it stops working and never returns the result of `facebookLogin.logIn(['email'])` or `googleSignIn.signIn();`

I would be very appreciative if you can help me with this issue, because I am out of ideas. The moment I remove the Braintree plugin, the social login starts working fine immediately. I have no explanation why this is happening as I think they have nothing in common.

**EDIT:** I have a little progress on the issue. Might be that the Braintree overrides something that Facebook uses to do the login and return a result. A friend of mine told me that it might be the onActivityResult function that is overridden and Facebook never reaches it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with the last version of the FlutterBraintree (0.5.3+1).
I forced it to stay at version 0.5.3 and it works.
I reported an issue on the FlutterBraintree repository

https://github.com/Pikaju/FlutterBraintree/issues/16